# Compute the automorphism group of $\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I saw this problem on my textbook.

What is that means compute the automorphism group of $\Bbb Z$,

Since I thought that automorphism is a properties. How to compute it?

Comment: Suppose you have an automorphism of $\mathbb Z$. What is the general form of such an automorphism? Hint:  $\mathbb Z$ is infinite cyclic.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг The general form of an automorphism is f(z)=z, so this answer is infinite?  That's actually what I thought in original, is that right?

Comment: This is one of the automorphisms, $f(z)=z$ for all $z$. There is one more, namely $f(z) = -z$, where we are basically taking one generator of $\mathbb Z$ to another, $1 \to -1$. You can show that these are the only two automorphisms. Actually, the answer below has done exactly that.

Comment: Automorphism is meant to be a "map" that is bijective and respects group opeartions and maps identity to identity (i.e. it is an isomorphism from a group to itself) . It's not a number or objects in a group. So what is asked is find all such maps

Comment: @user160738 Map identity to identity? I don't know this definition in automorphism, is that true?

Comment: @梁楷葳 oops, sorry, in fact any group homomorphism will send identity to identity, that's because $f(g)=f(ge)=f(g)f(e)$ for every $g$ in group and $e$ identity. But this is not stated as axiom for group homomorphism because it follows from other axioms. I confused groups with rings, where ring homomorphism must send identity to identity. In short, automorphism sends identity to identity but it's not supposed to be some kind of axiom required for automorphisms, because it follows from homomorphism properties.

Comment: @user160738 Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automorphism group of a group $G$ is a group consisting all the automorphism of $G$.

In fact the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}$ consists of identity function and function $\alpha$ where $$\alpha(x)=-x\;\;\forall x\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Note that $\mathbb{Z}=\langle 1\rangle$
Let $\alpha$ be an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$
Then $\alpha(1)=k$ for some integer $k$.
Also since $\alpha$ is onto, $\alpha(h)=1$ for some integer $h$.
That is, $h\alpha(1)=hk=1$
So $h=k=1$ or $h=k=-1$.

For $k=1$, $\alpha$ is identity function.
For $k=-1$, $\alpha$ sends every element to their own inverses.